# ExplicitExpansion() cause OData expand not work

Tags: asp.net-core, odata, automapper

When using ExplicitExpansion() Odata expand does not work.
My DTo and EF Models can be found below link.
[Querying DTOs based on EF using Odata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63450240/querying-dtos-based-on-ef-using-odata/63456016#63456016)

My Automapper class:

```
public class AutoMapperProfile : Profile
{
    public AutoMapperProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<ClientRef, ClientContract>().
        ForMember(dest => dest.ValidFrom,
        opt =>
        {
            opt.MapFrom(y => y.Clients.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ValidFrom <= DateTime.Now && x.ValidTo > DateTime.Now).ValidFrom);
        }).
        ForMember(dest => dest.ValidTo,
        opt =>
        {
            opt.MapFrom(y => y.Clients.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ValidFrom <= DateTime.Now && x.ValidTo > DateTime.Now).ValidTo);
        }).
       ForMember(dest => dest.FirstName,
        opt =>
        {
            opt.MapFrom(y => y.PhysicalPeople.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ValidFrom <= DateTime.Now && x.ValidTo > DateTime.Now).FirstName);
        }).
        ForMember(dest => dest.LastName,
        opt =>
        {
            opt.MapFrom(y => y.PhysicalPeople.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ValidFrom <= DateTime.Now && x.ValidTo > DateTime.Now).LastName);
        }).
        ForMember(dest => dest.BirthDate,
        opt =>
        {
            opt.MapFrom(y => y.PhysicalPeople.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ValidFrom <= DateTime.Now && x.ValidTo > DateTime.Now).BirthDate);
        }).
        ForMember(dest => dest.FatherName,
        opt =>
        {
            opt.MapFrom(y => y.PhysicalPeople.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ValidFrom <= DateTime.Now && x.ValidTo > DateTime.Now).FatherName);
        }).
        ForMember(dest => dest.CompanyName,
        opt =>
        {
            opt.MapFrom(y => y.Companies.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ValidFrom <= DateTime.Now && x.ValidTo > DateTime.Now).CompanyName);

        })
        .
        ForMember(dest => dest.PinNumber,
        opt =>
        {
            opt.MapFrom(y => y.PhysicalPeople.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ValidFrom <= DateTime.Now && x.ValidTo > DateTime.Now).Pin);

        }).
        ForMember(dest => dest.Position,
        opt =>
        {
            opt.MapFrom(y => y.PhysicalPeople.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ValidFrom <= DateTime.Now && x.ValidTo > DateTime.Now).Position);

        }).
        ForMember(dest => dest.PositionCustom,
        opt =>
        {
            opt.MapFrom(y => y.PhysicalPeople.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ValidFrom <= DateTime.Now && x.ValidTo > DateTime.Now).PositionCustom);

        }).
        ForMember(dest => dest.ClientType,
        opt =>
        {
            opt.MapFrom(y => y.Clients.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ValidFrom <= DateTime.Now && x.ValidTo > DateTime.Now).ClientType);

        })
        .
        ForMember(dest => dest.Documents,
        opt =>
        {
            opt.MapFrom(y => y.Documents.Where(x => x.ValidFrom <= DateTime.Now && x.ValidTo > DateTime.Now));
            //opt.ExplicitExpansion();
        })
        .ForMember(dest => dest.ContactsInfo,
        opt =>
        {
            opt.MapFrom(y => y.ClientContactInfoComps.Where(x => x.ValidFrom <= DateTime.Now && x.ValidTo > DateTime.Now).Select(x => x.ContactInfo));
            //opt.ExplicitExpansion();
        }).
        ForMember(dest => dest.ClientComment,
        opt =>
        {
            opt.MapFrom(y => y.CommentComps.Where(x => x.Contact == null).Select(x => x.Comment));
            //opt.ExplicitExpansion();
        }).
        ForMember(dest => dest.Relations,
        opt =>
        {
            opt.MapFrom(y => y.ClientRelationCompClient1Navigations);
            //opt.ExplicitExpansion();
        })
        ;


        CreateMap<Document, DocumentContract>();

        CreateMap<ContactInfo, ContactInfoContract>().
        ForMember(dest => dest.ContactComments,
        opt =>
        {
        opt.MapFrom(y => y.CommentComps.Select(x => x.Comment));
        });

        CreateMap<ClientRelationComp, RelationContract>().
            ForMember(dest => dest.ClientINN,
            opt => {
                opt.MapFrom(x => x.Client2);
            }).
            ForMember(dest => dest.RelationType,
            opt => {
                opt.MapFrom(x => x.RelationId);
            });

        CreateMap<ICollection<Client>, ClientContract>();
        CreateMap<ICollection<PhysicalPerson>, ClientContract>();
        CreateMap<ICollection<Company>, ClientContract>();
        CreateMap<Comment, CommentContract>();
        CreateMap<ICollection<Comment>, ICollection<ContactInfoContract>>();
        CreateMap<ICollection<ClientRelationComp>, ClientRef>();
        
    }
}
```

My Controller:

```
public class ClientContractController : ODataController
{
    CRMContext _context;
    IMapper _mapper;
    public ClientContractController(CRMContext ctx, IMapper mapper )
    {
        _context = ctx;
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    [EnableQuery(MaxExpansionDepth = 10)]
    public IQueryable<ClientContract> Get()
    {
        return _mapper.ProjectTo<ClientContract>(_context.ClientRefs).Where(x => x.ValidFrom <= DateTime.Now && x.ValidTo >= DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```

this gives the following exception
https://localhost:44371/odata/clientcontract?$expand=relations

System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression '$it' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.VisitMemberAssignment(MemberAssignment memberAssignment)
at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMemberBinding(MemberBinding node)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.VisitMemberInit(MemberInitExpression memberInitExpression)
at System.Linq.Expressions.MemberInitExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitLambda[T](Expression`1 node) at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
at System.Dynamic.Utils.ExpressionVisitorUtils.VisitArguments(ExpressionVisitor visitor, IArgumentProvider nodes)
at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.VisitMemberAssignment(MemberAssignment memberAssignment)
at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMemberBinding(MemberBinding node)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.VisitMemberInit(MemberInitExpression memberInitExpression)
at System.Linq.Expressions.MemberInitExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.VisitMemberAssignment(MemberAssignment memberAssignment)
at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMemberBinding(MemberBinding node)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.VisitMemberInit(MemberInitExpression memberInitExpression)
at System.Linq.Expressions.MemberInitExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.RelationalProjectionBindingExpressionVisitor.Translate(SelectExpression selectExpression, Expression expression)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.TranslateSelect(ShapedQueryExpression source, LambdaExpression selector)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query, Boolean async)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`1.<ExecuteAsync>b__0() at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.AsyncEnumerableReader.ReadInternal[T](Object value) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor.ExecuteAsyncEnumerable(ActionContext context, ObjectResult result, Object asyncEnumerable, Func`2 reader)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|21_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, IActionResult result)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|29_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 21/08/20202**

Without [explicit instructions](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html#explicit-expansion), `AutoMapper` will expand all members in the result.

To control which members are expanded during projection, set `ExplicitExpansion` in the configuration and then pass in the members you want to explicitly expand:

```
dbContext.Orders.ProjectTo<OrderDto>(configuration,
    dest => dest.Customer,
    dest => dest.LineItems);
// or string-based
dbContext.Orders.ProjectTo<OrderDto>(configuration,
    null,
    "Customer",
    "LineItems");
// for collections
dbContext.Orders.ProjectTo<OrderDto>(configuration,
    null,
    dest => dest.LineItems.Select(item => item.Product));
```

**Use the property name and not the attribute Name when use `OData`.**

`OData` client library relies on it's own attribute `OriginalNameAttribute` to gain knowledge about class/member names as server emits them. The details you can see from [here](https://github.com/OData/odata.net/issues/554).

Comment: Not worked. I removed DataContract/DataMember . But the exception is thrown

Comment: If I remove ExplicitExpansion() it works but 2 join generated in SQL. But if I added ExplicitExpansion I get exception above.

Comment: Maybe you could check this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36284142/using-dtos-with-odata-web-api). It same to yours

Comment: This works, but I discover other problem that, expand generates 2 left join to the same table.

Comment: @user3315759, if this issue is solved,  please [mark it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) for helping more people. And please check the answer I posted to  your left join problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.
There is other problem I saw that , always 2 join generated in SQL  without using ExplicitExpansion(). If I added ExplicitExpansion() and pass in members which i want to expand, then again 2 join is generated. What can be problem?

Comment: exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [c].[inn], [d].[document_expire_date], [d].[document_number], [d].[document_type], [d].[id], @__TypedProperty_1, [d0].[document_expire_date], [d0].[document_number], [d0].[document_type], [d0].[id], CAST(1 AS bit)
FROM [ClientRef] AS [c]
LEFT JOIN [Document] AS [d] ON [c].[inn] = [d].[inn]
LEFT JOIN [Document] AS [d0] ON [c].[inn] = [d0].[inn]
ORDER BY [c].[inn], [d].[id], [d0].[id]',N'@__TypedProperty_1 nvarchar(4000)',@__TypedProperty_1=N'c3b02432-1d14-4584-944e-0ddb16ce66e3'

Comment: Did you generate the SQL above, when use `$expand` to access `Get()`  controller?

Comment: yes, I got it from sql profiler with following link:
clientcontract?$expand=documents

Comment: do you see 2 left join to same table in sql server profiler?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't code complete your model in my project, I think it must be related with your model relationship(either a 1-1 or 1-N join) causing these duplicate left join.

Comment: It's huge model and takes time to read. But I‘m still following up with it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220414/discussion-between-lightman-and-user3315759).

Comment: I commented in chat