# Odata expand always generate left join

Tags: asp.net-core, odata, automapper

Odata expand always generate left join. And this causes not wanted data includes into result.
models can be found below links

[Querying DTOs based on EF using Odata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63450240/querying-dtos-based-on-ef-using-odata/63456016#63456016)

[ExplicitExpansion() cause OData expand not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63501923/explicitexpansion-cause-odata-expand-not-work)

Comment: You stated some information but I don't see a question.

Comment: The qeestion is that, how make odata dont generate left join automatically. I need some times left join some times inner join. How can I make it with odata using automapper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`OData` protocol doesn't support `JOIN` Operation like `SQL` (Inner / Outer / Left /Right). Relationships are represented as so called "navigation" properties. If the data is backed by a SQL table, the exact and complex join needs to be defined on the server api.

You can also use `$expand` which is similar to a multiple join.

`$expand` generates left join even for optional foreign keys.

> **Left join (default)**

**URL:**  /odata/clientcontract?$expand=ContactsInfo

[image]

> **Inner join**

**URL:**  /odata/clientcontract?$expand=ContactsInfo&$filter=ContactsInfo/any()

[image]